# Windows 7 + TLS problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, tls

We are facing a problem with many client. They are unable to access our website (which requires SSL) when they use Windows 7 and TLS 1.0 is enabled in browser (wither Firefox or IE). Website is accessible from Windows xp while TLS is enabled. Server OS is windows server 2003, website is developed on ASP.NET and hosted on IIS6.

I am unable to pin point the problem. I am a website developer and not a network administrator but has to provide assistance in order to solve the problem.

I used fiddler to see what is happening. On Windows XP, during handshake, session ID is filled by the server, but on windows 7, it doesn't.

http://i55.tinypic.com/eai2rl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with SSLv2 vs. SSLv3.  Try enabling SSLv2 in IE on the Windows 7 machine and see if that helps.

[image]